# saving explode character

Tags: php, save, character, explode

I have an essay and what I am trying to do is saving every sentence into my database. So I  explode the text with    **. ! ?**    characters. But when I do this I lose these characters. how can I explode a string without losing explode characters?

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't save it all in one go, or otherwise split it by, say, paragraph? (eg. `explode(PHP_EOL, $essay);`)

Comment: This is going to be *soooo* unreliable (sic!)........ (<--- 11 sentences)

Comment: Not that exploding against punctuation marks can be achieved more cleanly with str_word_count(), but that doesn't explain why you're exploding in the first place when you want the content to remain intact

Answer (score 4):

You could use PHP's [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php) function with the flag PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE set.

This will give you an array containing the sentences and the separators, but in separate array elements.

```
<?php
$string="Hello World. Test! Example 123? 456!";
$parts = preg_split("#([!.?])#", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

var_dump($parts);
?>
```

...will return the following:

```
array(9) { [0]=> string(11) "Hello World" [1]=> string(1) "." [2]=> string(5) " Test" [3]=> string(1) "!" [4]=> string(12) " Example 123" [5]=> string(1) "?" [6]=> string(4) " 456" [7]=> string(1) "!" [8]=> string(0) "" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use preg_split with the flag PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE:

```
$sentences = preg_split(
    '/([\?\.\!)/',
    $input,
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
);
```

The resulting array $sentences will runs as array(, , ..., ...)